# Macro to call a function that will run against all open worksheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

'I am trying to run a macro that will run a custom public function (Module title is ClearHTML or StripHTML() against every cell in every workbook. I am calling it by a single module which is called Remove_HTML or ClearHTMLShort(). Right now it is only pointing to an active sheet and focusing on column D. My gaol is to run a single macro and have it run through all populate cells of every worksheet within the workbook. Apologies I'm a bit new to this.

Tried by best with a custom function and then a macro to call the function for a single column.

```
Public Function StripHTML(cell As Range) As String
Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim sInput As String
Dim sOut As String
sInput = cell.Text
 
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "\x0D\x0A", Chr(10))
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "\x00", Chr(10))

    sInput = Replace(sInput, "</P>", Chr(10) & Chr(10))
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "<BR>", Chr(10))
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "<li>", "-")
     
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&#39;", "'")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ndash;", "–")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&mdash;", "—")

    sInput = Replace(sInput, "", "`")
   
With RegEx
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .MultiLine = True
   .Pattern = "<[^>]+>" 'Regular Expression for HTML Tags.
 
End With
    sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, "")
    StripHTML = sOut
    Set RegEx = Nothing
 
End Function
```

Code that calls the function:

```
Sub ClearHTMLshort() 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
  Dim c As Range 
   For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells 
     c.Value = StripHTML(c) 
   Next c 
Next ws 
End Sub
```

Comment: ' this is the macro that calls on the function'

Comment: Sub ClearHTMLshort()

   Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   Dim c As Range
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
            c.Value = StripHTML(c)
        Next c
   Next ws

End Sub

Comment: Please add that code to the question so that it's readable.

Comment: Why the hell would you correctly loop all worksheets with the for loop but then use activesheet instead of ws? Just use 'ws.UsedRange.Columns("D"').Cells', same as you did with the 'For Each c...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well answer this:

You are doing everything correctly to then mess it up with a single wrong statement. When you loop something using `For Each Foo in Bar`, `Foo` will be the object you want to use.

Change:
     `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells`

To:
    `ws.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells`

Comment: Thank you L8n for your help.